# Nodejs wait until async map function finishes executing

Tags: node.js, arrays, asynchronous

I have a array mapping and I need to execute some code after finishing the mapping.

Here is the array mapping code

```
    studentList.map( async index => {
      try{
        const student = await User.findOne({indexNumber: index})
        if (student == null) {
          emptyStudents.push(index)
        }
      }

      catch(err){
        console.log(err)
      }
    })
```

How can I do that? As this is asynchronous I was unable to find a solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the map to return the promises, and then when they are complete, outside of the map you can push onto your array -

```
const studentPromises = studentList.map( async index => {
    return User.findOne({indexNumber: index})
})

const studentResults = await Promise.all(studentPromises)

studentResults.forEach((student) => {
    if (student == null) {
        emptyStudents.push(index)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
await Promise.all(studentList.map( async index => {
  try{
    const student = await User.findOne({indexNumber: index})
    if (student == null) {
      emptyStudents.push(index)
    }
  }
}))
```

Comment: This is correct but a little explanation would be nice, esp as Promises can be difficult to wrap your head around at first.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to wrap your array mapping with `Promise` (and run it within `async` function):

```
await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  studentList.map( async index => {
    try{
      const student = await User.findOne({indexNumber: index})
      if (student == null) {
        emptyStudents.push(index)
      }
      if (studentList.length - 1 === index) {
        resolve();
      }
    }

    catch(err) {
      console.log(err);
      reject(err);
    }
  })
});

// YOUR CODE HERE
```